# Regex on limiting one occurrence of particular character

Tags: regex

I am working on a regex that allow a character 'x' and any digit from 0-9.

below are the rules.

- whole string must be in length of 4
- only accept 0-9 or 'x'
- **must have exactly one 'x'**

`^(x|[0-9])(x|[0-9])(x|[0-9])(x|[0-9])$`

My current regex only able rule 1 and 2, but it doesn't filter out those with more than one 'x'

```
x000 //ok
xxxx //ok , but should be not ok
23xx //ok , but should be not ok
a90d //not ok
11x1 //ok
x213 //ok
```

[sample regex editor here](http://www.rubular.com/r/mqnxyA5yLe)

*Since the regex will be used for validation in keyup so the rule must concern when the user type from one to four keyup.*

Updated rules

- whole string must be in length from 0 to 4
- only accept 0-9 or 'x'
- **cannot have more than one 'x'**

Comment: Are you using Ruby?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew No , I using that page to test only , I'm writing one for my validation in javascript , are they different?

Comment: You seem to be using [Robin Herbots `InputMask`](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) plugin, right? It only supports a regex per character. It does not apply the mask on the whole string.

Comment: yes , I think slitghly change the rule will work , https://jsfiddle.net/cxb2np75/25/ , this is the fiddle , the regex in your answer does able to control 4 character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
/^(?=[0-9x]{4}$)[0-9]*x[0-9]*$/
```

or

```
/^(?=[\dx]{4}$)\d*x\d*$/
```

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?=[\dx]{4}$)` - a positive lookahead checking that there are exactly 4 digits or `x` from the start up to the end of string
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `x` - an `x`
- `\d*` - 0+ digits
- `$` - end of string.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/mxNG96/1)

Note that in this case, you may even reduce the whole pattern to

```
/^(?=.{4}$)\d*x\d*$/
  ^^^^^^^^^
```

to just check the length of the string without checking the type of chars (since digits and `x` are non-linebreak chars).

Comment: how do this line work /^(?=.{4}$)\d*x\d*$/  , to check for only 1 x

Comment: @LeonArmstrong It is already explained. See **Details**. The `^\d*x\d*$` ensures only 1 `x`. `^(?=.{4}$)` makes sure the string is 4 char long.

Comment: Thanks , I got it now

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/cxb2np75/13/, I tried with my fiddle , the regex still able to key in multiple x , can you advice on this?

Comment: @LeonArmstrong Are you trying to restrict input into an HTML5 input field? You may only use `pattern` for validation on submit there.

Comment: this is a masking , its on keyup , so I think need to setup more rule , like the length should be from 0,4 . I will update the question.

Comment: You have made your question off-topic. Post the code inside the question body.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174800/discussion-between-leon-armstrong-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 2):

Use a look ahead for the “only 1 x” condition:

```
^(?=\d*x\d*$).{4}$
```

Comment: @tim the look ahead asserts there is exactly 1 x.

Comment: You may even reduce this to `^(?=\d*x\d*$).{4}$`, as there is no need to check for the specific pattern twice. However, I suggested `/^(?=.{4}$)\d*x\d*$/` in my answer, because checking the length at the start will fail a non-matching string faster (why check if a char is a digit or not if the length is not allowed).

Answer (score 0):

One option uses lookahead to handle the one `x` requirement:

```
^(?=.*x)(?!.*x.*x)[0-9x]{4}$
```

See the regex demo.

### Demo